# BOOST ASIO IO_Service and Socket

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

In order to achieve data locality, i am running an `io_service` thread per processor on a multi-processor system. I want to always send the data and read the data from the thread running io_`service` and adjacent to my execution core. But i find that the socket has a one-on-one relationship with the `io_service` and `io_service` has a one-on-one relationship with a thread. Is there a way i can assign one socket to a different `io_service`, after it was created?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043837/detaching-a-native-socket-from-boost-asios-socket-class

Comment: @diverscuba23 : Thanks, i looked at it, but i was looking for a portable way

Comment: this sounds like a premature optimization to me. Do you have a test case demonstrating your need for an io_service per thread?

Comment: @Gokul: unfortuately there is no provision within boost to move a socket from one io_service to another, so you have to do it manually, and that involves duplicating the native socket handle and passing it to a new socket that is bound to the desired io_service.

Comment: @Sam Miller : It is not io_service per thread, but io_service per thread group. In a multi-core multi-processor system, i want to minimize the data transport across processors.

Comment: @diverscuba : Thanks for that info. I was wondering whether i was misssing something. But is it because of ASIO's design limitation / not possible to design a socket, that can switch between io_services?

Comment: the reason this isn't easy to do is it isn't the normal mode of operation for most Asio programs. @diverscuba make your comment an answer